# how to get a property type from an content object in a map

Tags: java, reflection

The next code is an adaptation of my code and I hope it can help you.

Order.java

```
public class Order {
    ...
    private Long id = ...;
    private Map<Integer, Item> items = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Item>();
    ...
}
```

Item.java

```
public abstract class Item {

    public abstract Object getValue();
    public abstract void setValue(Object value);

}
```

ItemInt.java

```
public class ItemInt extends Item {

    private Integer number;

    @Override
    public Integer getValue() {
        return number; 
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        number = (Integer) value;
    }
}
```

ItemFloat.java

```
public class ItemFloat extends Item {

    private Float number;

    @Override
    public Float getValue() {
        return number; 
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        number = (Float) value;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the property type with the next string `"items[2].value"`and it doesn't work. How can I make it? The results would be `int` or `float`.

```
Order order = ...;
....
final Class<?> clazz = new PropertyUtilsBean().getPropertyType(order, "items[2].value");
```

Also, I have to access dynamically to other kind of objects with the same method. For example:

```
final Class<?> clazz = new PropertyUtilsBean().getPropertyType(order, "id");
```

**My real problem** is how to build this String to access to content object in a map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
public class Test {

    Map<Integer, Item> items = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Item>();

    // HashMap have method values(), but not property values.
    public List<Item> getValues() {
        return new ArrayList<Item>(items.values());
    }

    public abstract class Item {

        public abstract Object getValue();

        public abstract void setValue(Object value);

    }

    public class ItemInt extends Item {

        private Integer value;

        public Integer getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(Object value) {
            this.value = (Integer) value;
        }
    }

    public class ItemFloat extends Item {

        private Float value;

        public Float getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(Object value) {
            this.value = (Float) value;
        }
    }


    public Test() {

        ItemInt value = new ItemInt();
        value.setValue(1);
        items.put(0, value);


        ItemFloat itemFloat = new ItemFloat();
        itemFloat.setValue(4f);
        items.put(1, itemFloat);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
        Test test = new Test();

        Object property = new PropertyUtilsBean().getProperty(test, "values[0].value");
        System.err.println("" + property.getClass());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to do `items.get(<value>)` that will give you the item. However, that may be ItemInt  or ItemFloat. So, this is how we can get the item:

```
Item item = items.get(123);
if(item instanceof ItemInt){
//do something
}else if(item instanceof ItemFloat){
//do something else
}
```

This way, we will be able to know the item type. Once the item type is known, we can cast the value in corresponding Object.

Alternatively, if we want to get the value directly from item (assuming that Item value will always be a number then, we can modify

```
public abstract Object getValue();
```

to

```
public abstract Number getValue();
```

This way, we can directly do item.getValue() and assign it to Number instance.

***edited based on new/changed question***

We can probably use a List instead of a map here as it automatically orders objects and I can't see the use of Key in the above example. So, the updated Order class will be:

```
public class Order {
    ...
    private Long id = ...;
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    ...
}
```

Now, to get the item value from an order, we can write a method like the one below:

```
public Number getItemValue(Order order, int index) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    if(order.getItems().size() < index){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid index.");
    }
    return order.getItems().get(index-1).getValue();
}
```

We can change the return type to Object if values are not just numbers. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but Float and Int is an adaptation of my real problem. I have more complex objects behind and I've used Integer and Float for abbreviating. I'm going to edit my question because I didn't say I can to access to other kind of objects dynamically.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please check and let me know if it helps?